# target span element within anchor

Tags: jquery, css

Quick question:

I have this html markup:

```html
<ul class="category_list">    
<a href="...">
<span class="category_item"></span>
<span class="category_description">Handy & Co.</span>
</a>
```

and this JS:

```js
$('.category_list a').each(function (){...}
```

Right now I am targeting all the `<a>` within `category_list`.

How can I target one specific `<span>` element (within the `<a>`) rather than only the `<a>`?

Comment: Do you want to use the span elements within the anonymous function for each a block, or are you wanting to just get one single span?

Answer (score 3):

You can just add `span` in your selector:

```
$('.category_list a span').each(function (){...}
```

For your example i assume you can select it inside iterator for example:

```
$('.category_list a').each(function(){
    $(this).children('span');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This selector selects all `<span>`s that are children of `<a>`s that are children of `.category_list`.

`$('.category_list > a > span').each(function (){...}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get one single span inside the a elament you can do this using .get() function
http://api.jquery.com/get/

`$('.category_list a span').get(0)`

or if you want to iterate through all of the spans do this

`$('.category_list a span').each(function (i,e){...}`

i is for index of current span 
e is element itself

Answer (score 2):

Just do this

```
$('.category_list a:contains(About)').each(function (){...}
```

The above targets any **a** that's inside **.category_list** and also contains the word **About**

**Note:** The  "has" selector is case sensitive